Series expansion involving integrals of higher derivatives and Bernoulli polynomials
Given a (smooth) function f defined on $[0, 1]$, I am looking for a series expansion of the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!} P_n(x),
$$
where $c_n = \int_{0}^{1} f^{(n)}(t) dt$, where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$-th derivative of $f$.
Looking for properties of such a series expansion, we get the natural following constraints on the family of functions $P_n$:

Deriving the series expansion should give us the series expansion of $f'$, which yields the constraints $P_{n+1}'(x) = (n +1) P_{n}(x)$ and $P_0'(x) = 0$.
Integrating between 0 and 1 should give us back $c_0$, which yields $\int_0^1 P_0(x) = 1$ and $\int_0^1 P_{n}(x) = 0$ if $n > 0$.

This implies that the functions $P_n$ are none other than the Bernoulli polynomials.
Has this sort of thing be studied ? Does this series converge on $[0, 1]$ ?
I have tried to make it at least formally fit into a Sturm-Liouville / Generalised Fourier Series kind of picture, but even using distributions I don't see a direct link between the distribution $(f \mapsto \int_{0}^{1} f^{(n)}(t) dt)$ and Bernoulli polynomials.

Just realised that this series does not converge towards the original function even for very bell-behaved funtions: take $f(t) = cos(2 \pi t)$ : then for all $n \geq 0$, $c_n = \int_{0}^{1} f^{(n)}(t) dt = 0$, and the series is identically null.
